# Why do JodaTime and Calendar return different results

Tags: java, time, calendar, jodatime

Why does this test fail:

```
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1997,01,01,00,00,00,00, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    long jodaMills = dateTime.getMillis();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.set(1997,01,01,00,00,00);
    long calMills = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Assert.assertEquals(jodaMills, calMills);
```

I get a result of:
Expected :852076800000
Actual   :854755200964

Shouldn't they be the same number?

Comment: Is there a reason you use octal numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Joda has one based months. So you need to change that.
2. Calendar is poorly designed. You are not setting the milliseconds of the second to 0. `cal.set(MILLISECOND, 0)`

Here is the javadoc

> public final void set(int year,
>                         int month,
>                         int date,
>                         int hourOfDay,
>                         int minute,
>                         int second)

Which is missing the millisecond field.

Comment: This is also why the milliseconds don't match

Comment: do'h! I knew that too...it always gets me.

Answer (score 22):

Calendar has zero based months, and JodaTime months fields starts at 1.

So, in JodaTime, January is month 1, but in Calendar, January is month 0.

Therefore, in your example you are comparing **January 1st** to **February 1st**, hence the difference in values.

There is also a difference in milliseconds, as the JodaTime is being set to zero, but the Calendar object is not.

Answer (score 4):

Zero-based vs. one-based notations

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess here that `1997, 01,01` for Joda means **January 1st, 1997**.

But in Java Calendar, months are numbered from 0 - 11, so 1997,01,01 **for Java is actually February 1st.**

A better approach is to use --

```
cal.set(1997, Calendar.JANUARY, 01, 00,00,00);
```

You should also reset the MILLISECONDS of the Calendar object to 0 as @Amir pointed out.